# Use split within split in Typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Using typoscript, how do I split a field by linebreak and then split each line by `:` ?

This is what I have tried:

```
30 = TEXT
30.stdWrap {
    field = abstract
    split {
        token.char = 10
        wrap = <p>|</p>
        1.current = 1
        1.stdWrap.split {
            token = :
            wrap = <span>|</span>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, it's worth a look at [`dataProcessing`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing.html)...

There is also a [CommaSeparatedValueProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/CommaSeparatedValueProcessor.html) which can provide CVS-like data prepared as single values for use in Fluid.

Comment: I am using TYPO3 7.6 and this is for a menu. There doesn't appear to be a menuProcessor in that version, so I'd end up having a template file in the middle of an HMENU which seems a bit messy?

Answer (score 1):

`split` works with some global properties, so, nesting `split` results into interference with values from previous `split`. I prefer using individual ContentObjects:

```
page.10 = COA
page.10.10 = LOAD_REGISTER
page.10.10.splitParts = vorname:stefan,nachname:froemken
page.10.10.splitParts.split {
  token = ,
  1.current = 1
}

page.10.20 = TEXT
page.10.20.data = REGISTER:splitParts
page.10.20.wrap = <p>|</p>
page.10.20.split {
  token = :
  wrap = <span>|</span>
  1.current = 1
}

page.10.30 = RESTORE_REGISTER
```

Stefan